# How do I send pictures to a C# service?

Tags: typescript, angular

How do I send in Angular2 image ( jpg, png , gif) to the service written in C #, the service actually needs to send string using Base64 GET method, but so long not get sent , returns an error 414. How, then send the images ? By post? Some other way?

**HTML**

```
<h2>Input</h2>  
<form class="input-group" id="img2b64">
    <input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" />
</form>

<hr>

<h2>Output</h2>        
<div class="output">
    <textarea class="form-control"></textarea><br>
    <a></a><br><br>
    <img><br>
</div>
```

**JS Code**

```
function encodeImageFileAsURL(cb) {
    return function(){
        var file = this.files[0];
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            cb(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}

$('#inputFileToLoad').change(encodeImageFileAsURL(function(base64Img){
    $('.output')
      .find('textarea')
        .val(base64Img)
        .end()
      .find('a')
        .attr('href', base64Img)
        .text(base64Img)
        .end()
      .find('img')
        .attr('src', base64Img);
}));
```

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: I did the same as here http://jsfiddle.net/xztfbx1m/, the image has been converted to base64 , variable reader.result I joined as a parameter in the url

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement in one of the apps I have developed and I am converting the image to base64 and then sending it inside the body of a POST request. So yes, you should do a POST request instead of a GET request.